# Why won't bitwise calculator program print?

Tags: c

This program is meant to function as a bitwise calculator...A #define called BITS should be set at the top of the program. It should be set to 8 when the program is submitted. This
define should be used throughout the entire program when setting/using array sizes/max element. This define will also be used in the output to print 8-bit vs 16 bit. Your program should function whether the define is set to 8 or to 16. Part of the grading process will be to change the define from 8 to 16 and to recompile your program to see if your program still runs properly.

```
#define BITS 8
#include <stdio.h>

char binary[BITS + 1];
int operator[]={38,60,62,94,124};
void convertDecimalToBinary();

int main() 
{

void bitwiseCalc()
{
int k = 0,j = 1;
char expr[10];
int firstNum,secondNum,bitwiseOperator,resultNum;
char firstNumber[BITS+1],secondNumber[BITS+1],resultNumber[BITS+1];
printf("Enter Expression ");
scanf("%s",expr);
firstNum = expr[0] - 48;
while(k != 1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        if(expr[j] == operator[i])
        {
            k = 1;
            bitwiseOperator = expr[j];
            if(expr[j] == 60 || expr[j] == 62)
            {
                for(int z = j+3;expr[z] != '\0';z++)
                {
                    secondNum = secondNum*10 + expr[j] - 48;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    if (k == 0 && expr[j] != 32)
    {
        firstNum = firstNum*10 + expr[j++] - 48;
    }  
}
if (expr[j] != 60 && expr[j] != 62)
{
    for(int z = j+2;expr[z] != '\0';z++)
    {
        secondNum = secondNum*10 + expr[z] - 48;
    }
}
        
convertDecimalToBinary(firstNum);
for(int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1;x++)
{
    firstNumber[x] = binary[x];
}

convertDecimalToBinary(secondNum);
for(int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1;x++)
{
    secondNumber[x] = binary[x];
}

printf("\nIn base 10...\n");
if(bitwiseOperator == 60 ||bitwiseOperator == 62)
{
    printf("%d %c%c %d",firstNum,bitwiseOperator,bitwiseOperator,secondNum);
}
else
{
    printf("%d %c %d",firstNum,bitwiseOperator,secondNum);
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
    if(bitwiseOperator == operator[i])
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
            resultNum = firstNum & secondNum;
            break;
            case 1:
            resultNum = firstNum << secondNum;
            break;
            case 2:
            resultNum = firstNum >> secondNum;
            break;
            case 3:
            resultNum = firstNum ^ secondNum;
            break;
            case 4:
            resultNum = firstNum | secondNum;
            break;
        }
    }
}
printf(" = %d\n",resultNum);
convertDecimalToBinary(resultNum);

for(int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1;x++)
{
    resultNumber[x] = binary[x];
}
printf("In %d-bit base 2...\n",BITS);
for(int i = 0;i < BITS;i++)
{
    printf("%d",firstNumber[i]);
}
if(bitwiseOperator == 60 || bitwiseOperator == 62)
{
    printf(" %c%c %d\n",bitwiseOperator,bitwiseOperator,secondNum);
}
else
{
    printf("\n %c\n",bitwiseOperator);
    for(int i = 0;i < BITS;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",secondNumber[i]);
    }   
}
printf("\n========\n");
for(int i = 0;i < BITS;i++)
{
    printf("%d",resultNumber[i]);
}

}
void convertDecimalToBinary(int num)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < BITS)
    {   
        binary[i] = num & (1 << i);
        i++;
    }   
binary[BITS] = '\0';
}
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have nested functions. Either you pasted your code incorrectly or this code doesn't even compile, much less run-but-not-print.

Comment: Your program would be so much easier to read and understand if you used actual character constants like `'&'`, etc.

Comment: Just fyi, look at `secondNum = secondNum * 10 + expr[j] - 48` in your inner-for-loop of `bitwiseCalc`. Now ask yourself, "What is the value of `secondNum` *before* that line executes?" The answer is *no one knows*. The variable `secondNum` has no initial determinate value in that function, so performing operations the require prior/initial value is nonsense. I can't tell you what `a` is when I do `a = a+1` without first knowing what `a` was in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You define two nested functions within `main()`.  You never call either, so they aren't executed.  You define `void bitwiseCalc()` and `void convertDecimalToBinary(int num)`.

Here's your code reformatted:

```
/* SO 6432-7320 */
#define BITS 8
#include <stdio.h>

char binary[BITS + 1];
int operator[] = {38, 60, 62, 94, 124};
void convertDecimalToBinary();

int main()
{
    void bitwiseCalc()
    {
        int k = 0, j = 1;
        char expr[10];
        int firstNum, secondNum, bitwiseOperator, resultNum;
        char firstNumber[BITS + 1], secondNumber[BITS + 1], resultNumber[BITS + 1];
        printf("Enter Expression ");
        scanf("%s", expr);
        firstNum = expr[0] - 48;
        while (k != 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (expr[j] == operator[i])
                {
                    k = 1;
                    bitwiseOperator = expr[j];
                    if (expr[j] == 60 || expr[j] == 62)
                    {
                        for (int z = j + 3; expr[z] != '\0'; z++)
                        {
                            secondNum = secondNum * 10 + expr[j] - 48;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (k == 0 && expr[j] != 32)
            {
                firstNum = firstNum * 10 + expr[j++] - 48;
            }
        }
        if (expr[j] != 60 && expr[j] != 62)
        {
            for (int z = j + 2; expr[z] != '\0'; z++)
            {
                secondNum = secondNum * 10 + expr[z] - 48;
            }
        }

        convertDecimalToBinary(firstNum);
        for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
        {
            firstNumber[x] = binary[x];
        }

        convertDecimalToBinary(secondNum);
        for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
        {
            secondNumber[x] = binary[x];
        }

        printf("\nIn base 10...\n");
        if (bitwiseOperator == 60 || bitwiseOperator == 62)
        {
            printf("%d %c%c %d", firstNum, bitwiseOperator, bitwiseOperator, secondNum);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d %c %d", firstNum, bitwiseOperator, secondNum);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (bitwiseOperator == operator[i])
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                case 0:
                    resultNum = firstNum & secondNum;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    resultNum = firstNum << secondNum;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    resultNum = firstNum >> secondNum;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    resultNum = firstNum ^ secondNum;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    resultNum = firstNum | secondNum;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf(" = %d\n", resultNum);
        convertDecimalToBinary(resultNum);

        for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
        {
            resultNumber[x] = binary[x];
        }

        printf("In %d-bit base 2...\n", BITS);
        for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", firstNumber[i]);
        }
        if (bitwiseOperator == 60 || bitwiseOperator == 62)
        {
            printf(" %c%c %d\n", bitwiseOperator, bitwiseOperator, secondNum);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n %c\n", bitwiseOperator);
            for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
            {
                printf("%d", secondNumber[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n========\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", resultNumber[i]);
        }
    }

    void convertDecimalToBinary(int num)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < BITS)
        {
            binary[i] = num & (1 << i);
            i++;
        }
        binary[BITS] = '\0';
    }
}
```

You must be using GCC (or perhaps Clang in GCC-compatibility mode) for nested functions to even compile; they are not a part of standard C.  You should stop trying to use them.  This also shows the importance of good (consistent) code formatting.  It was really hard to spot that in your code as presented here.

To fix: move your function definitions outside of `main()` and call `bitwiseCalc()` in `main()`.  There are still multiple other problems that have not been fixed.

```
/* SO 6432-7320 */
#define BITS 8
#include <stdio.h>

char binary[BITS + 1];
int operator[] = {38, 60, 62, 94, 124};
void convertDecimalToBinary(int num);
void bitwiseCalc(void);

void bitwiseCalc(void)
{
    int k = 0, j = 1;
    char expr[10];
    int firstNum, secondNum, bitwiseOperator, resultNum;
    char firstNumber[BITS + 1], secondNumber[BITS + 1], resultNumber[BITS + 1];
    printf("Enter Expression ");
    scanf("%s", expr);
    firstNum = expr[0] - 48;
    while (k != 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (expr[j] == operator[i])
            {
                k = 1;
                bitwiseOperator = expr[j];
                if (expr[j] == 60 || expr[j] == 62)
                {
                    for (int z = j + 3; expr[z] != '\0'; z++)
                    {
                        secondNum = secondNum * 10 + expr[j] - 48;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (k == 0 && expr[j] != 32)
        {
            firstNum = firstNum * 10 + expr[j++] - 48;
        }
    }
    if (expr[j] != 60 && expr[j] != 62)
    {
        for (int z = j + 2; expr[z] != '\0'; z++)
        {
            secondNum = secondNum * 10 + expr[z] - 48;
        }
    }

    convertDecimalToBinary(firstNum);
    for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
    {
        firstNumber[x] = binary[x];
    }

    convertDecimalToBinary(secondNum);
    for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
    {
        secondNumber[x] = binary[x];
    }

    printf("\nIn base 10...\n");
    if (bitwiseOperator == 60 || bitwiseOperator == 62)
    {
        printf("%d %c%c %d", firstNum, bitwiseOperator, bitwiseOperator, secondNum);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d %c %d", firstNum, bitwiseOperator, secondNum);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (bitwiseOperator == operator[i])
        {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 0:
                resultNum = firstNum & secondNum;
                break;
            case 1:
                resultNum = firstNum << secondNum;
                break;
            case 2:
                resultNum = firstNum >> secondNum;
                break;
            case 3:
                resultNum = firstNum ^ secondNum;
                break;
            case 4:
                resultNum = firstNum | secondNum;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", resultNum);
    convertDecimalToBinary(resultNum);

    for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
    {
        resultNumber[x] = binary[x];
    }

    printf("In %d-bit base 2...\n", BITS);
    for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", firstNumber[i]);
    }
    if (bitwiseOperator == 60 || bitwiseOperator == 62)
    {
        printf(" %c%c %d\n", bitwiseOperator, bitwiseOperator, secondNum);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n %c\n", bitwiseOperator);
        for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", secondNumber[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n========\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", resultNumber[i]);
    }
}

void convertDecimalToBinary(int num)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < BITS)
    {
        binary[i] = num & (1 << i);
        i++;
    }
    binary[BITS] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    bitwiseCalc();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the source file `nest41.c`, I get errors like these:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic nest41.c -o nest41 
nest41.c: In function ‘bitwiseCalc’:
nest41.c:52:32: error: iteration 9 invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimization]
   52 |         firstNumber[x] = binary[x];
      |                          ~~~~~~^~~
nest41.c:50:5: note: within this loop
   50 |     for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
      |     ^~~
nest41.c:58:33: error: iteration 9 invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimization]
   58 |         secondNumber[x] = binary[x];
      |                           ~~~~~~^~~
nest41.c:56:5: note: within this loop
   56 |     for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
      |     ^~~
nest41.c:99:33: error: iteration 9 invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimization]
   99 |         resultNumber[x] = binary[x];
      |                           ~~~~~~^~~
nest41.c:97:5: note: within this loop
   97 |     for (int x = 0; x <= BITS + 1; x++)
      |     ^~~
nest41.c:52:24: error: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ forming offset 9 is out of the bounds [0, 9] of object ‘firstNumber’ with type ‘char[9]’ [-Werror=array-bounds]
   52 |         firstNumber[x] = binary[x];
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:15:10: note: ‘firstNumber’ declared here
   15 |     char firstNumber[BITS + 1], secondNumber[BITS + 1], resultNumber[BITS + 1];
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:58:25: error: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ forming offset 9 is out of the bounds [0, 9] of object ‘secondNumber’ with type ‘char[9]’ [-Werror=array-bounds]
   58 |         secondNumber[x] = binary[x];
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:15:33: note: ‘secondNumber’ declared here
   15 |     char firstNumber[BITS + 1], secondNumber[BITS + 1], resultNumber[BITS + 1];
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:99:25: error: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ forming offset 9 is out of the bounds [0, 9] of object ‘resultNumber’ with type ‘char[9]’ [-Werror=array-bounds]
   99 |         resultNumber[x] = binary[x];
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:15:57: note: ‘resultNumber’ declared here
   15 |     char firstNumber[BITS + 1], secondNumber[BITS + 1], resultNumber[BITS + 1];
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:131:25: error: ‘resultNum’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
  131 |         binary[i] = num & (1 << i);
      |                     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:14:47: note: ‘resultNum’ was declared here
   14 |     int firstNum, secondNum, bitwiseOperator, resultNum;
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~
nest41.c:31:47: error: ‘secondNum’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   31 |                         secondNum = secondNum * 10 + expr[j] - 48;
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

All those should be fixed before you try running the program.  In particular, the loops should be `for (int i = 0; i < BITS; i++)` — or maybe `BITS + 1` — I've not studied the logic there; the key point is using `<` rather than `<=` for the test against the upper bound.